# Как сделать такое закругление на кнопке?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Как закруглить так кнопку при помощи css ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы где эту кнопку взяли?

Comment: всегда есть svg, если css не справляется

Answer (score 5):

Как пример. Дальше самостоятельно)

```css
body {
  background: #f3edef;
}

button {
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e0121e;
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #ec212b, #fa7169);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px / 200% 200%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(255, 111, 170, 0.75);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px gray, 0 0 1em red;
}
```

```html
<button>Принять участие и получить бонус</button>
```

upd. Еще один пример на скорую руку. Полностью воспроизвести такую кнопку, как на картинке, цели такой не имею. Причина вполне оправдана - автор самостоятельно и не пытался этого сделать, судя по его вопросу (отсутствие какого-либо кода). Поэтому просто пара примеров для автора вопроса для того, чтобы показать, что с помощью CSS это сделать вполне возможно и несложно.

```css
body {
  background: #f3edef;
}

button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 30px 50px 25px 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e0121e;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px / 500% 500%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(255, 111, 170, 0.75);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px gray, 0 0 1em red;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  background: red;
}

button::before {
  top: -5px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0 / 500% 500%;
}

button::after {
  bottom: -10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px / 500% 500%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e0121e;
}
```

```html
<button>Принять участие и получить бонус</button>
```

Comment: по сабжу 1 строка про решение и тонна воды. причем border-radius не дает нужного автору решения.

Comment: и в чем тут пример, показать что есть `border-radius`? Я не особо,конечно, в верстке специалист, но что-то не уверен что с помощью border-radius можно получить желаемый результат.

Comment: потому что сказать что "о, вам нужен border-radius" это примерно "ого, да вам css тут надо использовать". не ответ это. Вы либо дайте код, который реально похож на то что пытается реализовать автор, либо словами опишите, что помимо border-radius надо использовать, чтобы достичь требуемого результата. Иначе ответ ваш бесполезен.

Comment: я считаю ваш ответ в его первоначальном виде некачественным

Comment: это уже дискуссия для меты. Плохой вопрос - не повод писать плохой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.rect {
  width: 380px;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, tomato, red);
  z-index: 2;
}

.rect:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, tomato, darkred);
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rect:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: 1px;
  background: inherit;
  width: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.rect:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: 1px;
  background: inherit;
  width: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.rect:after,
.rect:before {
  z-index: ;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="rect">
    <button>Принять участие и получить бонус</button>
  </div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Что-то похожее на ваш запрос:

```css
button.example {
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-out;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 4px 20px 0;
    margin: 10px auto;
    left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button.pinterest {
    border-left: solid 1px #C02B21;
    background: #DE463B;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21;
}

button.example:active {
    top: 3px;
}

button.pinterest:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #C02B21;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #C02B21;
}

button.pinterest:after {
    border-right: solid 1px #C02B21;
    background: #DE463B;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21;
}

button.pinterest:active:after {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21, 6px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #C02B21, 6px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<button class="example pinterest">Pin this!</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению не так она всё таки закруглена

Comment: @Egor Pyshnov если верстаете с макета, открываете Фотошоп или тот же авокод, там есть border-radius. Если просто с фото, можете сами подобрать с помощью разрешения Pixel Perfect